# Questions about the tense for the dependent clause when the independent clause has the present perfect tense

Tags: tense

I have described how to get the answer with an assumption.
After the description, I want to use the following sentence, but I don't know which is correct.

> Note that all derivations have been made on the assumption that it is selected as the source node.

vs

> Note that all derivations have been made on the assumption that it has been selected as the source node.

vs

> Note that all derivations have been made on the assumption that it was selected as the source node.

I think one of these three must be correct.
Which one is correct?

Comment: What does the **it** refer to?

Comment: @RonaldSole it refers to "the ith node"

Comment: Both 1) and 3) are correct.

Comment: All three look all right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have specified what the word **it** refers to, the most concise and clearest option is 1.

> Note that all derivations have been made on the assumption that it is selected as the source node.

Number 2 is grammatically correct but takes more words to say the same thing.

Number 3 is possible too but the present perfect passive (have been made) works better with the present (is selected).

So your question is really not about grammar or correctness, but about aptness - which one works best.

In short, prefer 1.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I really want to know.